# Using a product with Windows only drivers on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

I want to use a [Triton USB to VGA adapter](http://www.trittonaudio.com/prod/parts-video.asp#!prettyPhoto) that I have, however I am running Linux (Ubuntu) and their [drivers page](http://support.madcatz.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/286/7/where-can-i-find-drivers-for-my-tritton-products) only shows support for Windows. The purpose of this is to get 3 screens. I already have two and another graphics card will not fit. I have tried to simply plug the device in and hope it works however it does not

Is is possible to get this working on Linux, or not?

Comment: Most device manufacturers do not support Linux. However some are standards compliant, others are supported by Linux. Some are not supported. Note the inversion in the direction of support.

Comment: Its not possible to use a Windows driver on Linux. If there isn't a Linux driver for your device then you will need to locate a device that does have a Linux driver. In the case of the example provide, the Linux kernel didn't actual use a Windows driver, that would make no sense considering a driver is a layer over Win32.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the output of the *lsusb* command, ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't generally use Windows drivers in Linux, but it looks like at least some of the Triton USB to VGA adapters already work in Linux. [This guy](http://patentpondering.blogspot.ca/2011/02/triton-see2-xtreme-uv200-in-linux.html) gets his Triton SEE2 Xtreme UV200 working in Linux, for example. In general, Linux supports much more hardware out of the box than Windows does. To be clear, you expect in Windows to have to install drivers, while in Linux, you expect the drivers to already be offered by the kernel. Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I plugged the adapter in though and there still was no input being sent to the monitor.